# Windows 10 auto connect to two WiFi at boot

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have two WiFi networks.  One is for the internet, the other (which does eventually also route through to the internet) is for a special purpose internal network.

I have Windows 10 Pro (and Ubuntu dual boot, but Ubuntu behaves as it should...), and two WiFi interfaces.

The WiFi interfaces are each configured to connect to one of the two networks (one is 5GHz and only one interface is capable of connecting to that, which makes separation easier...).  That's all fine and dandy. Everything works.

But, as soon as I reboot only one of the WiFi networks connects. I have to go in an manually connect the other.

- I have tried setting the `ConnectionType` to `auto` in `netsh wlan...` but it has made no difference.
- I am using static IP address allocation and only one of the interfaces has a default gateway set up on it.
- If I disable the internet connection WiFi the other WiFi instantly connects. As soon as I re-enable the internet WiFi the internal network WiFi disconnects.

Is there some setting in Windows (ideally a global one that affects the whole operating system) to say "Do what I tell you, not what you think I want, which is invariably wrong!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows insists on connecting to only one of the networks, you can automate
the connection to the other one.

Start a Command Prompt and run the command:

```
netsh wlan show profile
```

This will list your network profile. Suppose that SSID is the name of the network
that never gets connected.

Test that is can be connected by using the command:

```
netsh wlan connect name=SSID
```

If this works, you may set this command to be run automatically after login by,
using the Task Scheduler to run a `.bat` file that contains this command.

This is a workaround, but it will solve the problem.

Comment: That works, except I had to specify the SSID *and* the interface as well.  `netsh wlan connect name=SSID ssid=SSID interface="The Name Of The Right Interface"`

Comment: Yes,  I should have remembered that you have two of them.

Comment: The problem is now solved?

Comment: Well I wouldn't say solved. Worked around more like. It's a solution but maybe not the best. I'm holding out for a proper fix before I accept this answer.

Comment: In the mean time you can have an up-vote.